# Software tool to create/modify/view table relationships in SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite

I would like to have a software tool to create/modify/view table relationships in a SQLite database *in a visual way*, something like the picture below. For a MySQL database, I can use the MySQL workbench to view 1-to-many relationships. Is there an equivalent tool for SQLite?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) is also a great tool to work with databases including SQLite and can visualize the relations between tables

Comment: Great software recommendation. I have changed the best answer to yours.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 6):

The *viewing* part can be achieved using [SchemaCrawler](http://www.schemacrawler.com); amongst its features, it [generates database diagrams](http://www.schemacrawler.com/diagramming.html). It supports various database formats, [including SQLite](http://www.schemacrawler.com/diagram-examples/diagram.png). Disclaimer: I haven't used it (yet).

Here is an example image, found on the [roman10](http://www.roman10.net/2018/04/10/visualize-sqlite-database-schema/) website.

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of apps which will let you modify an existing  database, which this answer does not claim. Since you accepted this answer, I won't go into detail, but GIYF (my personal recommendation is https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=gallery)

Answer (score 2):

[Datagrip by jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) supports SQLite. I've used it for other (MySQL, Oracle) types of databases, and it's been good. However, I haven't used it for SQLite.